# What is the purpose of the "Size" option when you right-click a Windows title bar?

Tags: windows, windows-10

In every version of Windows, when you right-click a title bar, there is a "Size" option. Selecting "Size" typically moves the mouse to the center of the current window, and changes the cursor. 
What is the actual purpose of this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Once the "Size" option is selected, you can then use the arrows keys on your keyboard to adjust the size of the current window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Windows only with a keyboard. So every mouse command has a key equivalent.

From *The Windows Interface Guidelines — A Guide for Designing Software*, Microsoft, 1995

> **Resizing Windows**
>
> Make your primary windows resizable unless the
>   information displayed in the window is fixed, such as in the Windows
>   Calculator program. The system provides several conventions that
>   support user resizing of a window. Sizing Borders The user resizes a
>   primary window by dragging the sizing border with the mouse or pen at
>   the edge of a window or by using the Size command on the window's
>   menu. On most configurations, an outline representation of the window
>   moves with the pointer. (A display property setting allows the user to
>   have the system dynamically redraw the window as it is sized.) After
>   completing the size operation, the window assumes its new size. Using
>   the keyboard, the user can size the window by choosing the Size
>   command, using the arrow keys, and pressing the ENTER key.